# Clickhouse. Problem using python module clickhouse_driver

Tags: python, clickhouse

I am trying to execute select queries to clickhouse using python module clickhouse_driver:

```
from django.conf import settings
from clickhouse_driver import Client

CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS = settings.CLICKHOUSE
clickhouse_client = Client(**CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS)

def get_data_1():
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_1 ")
    return data_1

def get_data_2():
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_2 ")
    return data_1

def get_data_3():
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_3 ")
    return data_1

def get_data_4():
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_4 ")
    return data_1
```

and get error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 248, in execute
    rv = self.process_ordinary_query(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 446, in process_ordinary_query
    return self.receive_result(with_column_types=with_column_types,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 113, in receive_result   
    return result.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/result.py", line 50, in get_result
    for packet in self.packet_generator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 129, in packet_generator
    packet = self.receive_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 143, in receive_packet
    packet = self.connection.receive_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 490, in receive_packet
    raise errors.UnknownPacketFromServerError(
clickhouse_driver.errors.UnknownPacketFromServerError: Code: 100. Unknown packet 4 from server None:None
```

In this sample i am using one instance of Client for all queries. But when i am creating instance of Client for each query then everything is fine.

```
from django.conf import settings
from clickhouse_driver import Client

CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS = settings.CLICKHOUSE


def get_data_1():
    clickhouse_client = Client(**CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS)
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_1 ")
    return data_1

def get_data_2():
    clickhouse_client = Client(**CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS)
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_2 ")
    return data_1

def get_data_3():
    clickhouse_client = Client(**CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS)
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_3 ")
    return data_1

def get_data_4():
    clickhouse_client = Client(**CLICKHOUSE_SETTINGS)
    data_1 = clickhouse_client.execute("SELECT * from table_4 ")
    return data_1
```

Why i got error in the first case?

Comment: https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-and-multithreading

Comment: do all these methods call one by one? not simultaneously (not async)?

Answer (score 1):

Django sends queries to clickhouse with multithreading which clickhouse_driver does not support. That is the reason.

Using SQLAlchemy fixed my problem.